# Postgres db index not being used on Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to debug a slow query for a model that looks like:

```
class Employee(TimeStampMixin):
    title = models.TextField(blank=True,db_index=True)
    seniority = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=128,db_index=True)
```

The query is: `Employee.objects.exclude(seniority='').filter(title__icontains=title).order_by('seniority').values_list('seniority')`

When I run it locally it takes ~0.3 seconds (same database size). An explain locally shows:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.58..196218.23 rows=7 width=1) (actual time=299.016..300.366 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: seniority
  Buffers: shared hit=2447163 read=23669
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.58..196218.23 rows=7 width=1) (actual time=299.015..300.364 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: seniority
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=2447163 read=23669
        ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using companies_e_seniori_12ac68_idx on public.companies_employee  (cost=0.56..195217.40 rows=3 width=1) (actual time=293.195..293.200 rows=0 loops=3)
              Output: seniority
              Filter: (((companies_employee.seniority)::text <> ''::text) AND (upper(companies_employee.title) ~~ '%INFORMATION SPECIALIST%'::text))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2697599
              Heap Fetches: 2819
              Buffers: shared hit=2447163 read=23669
              Worker 0:  actual time=291.087..291.088 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=820222 read=7926
              Worker 1:  actual time=291.056..291.056 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=812538 read=7888
Planning Time: 0.209 ms
Execution Time: 300.400 ms
```

however when I run the same code on Heroku I get execution times of 3s+, possibly because the former is using an index while the second is not:

```
Limit  (cost=216982.74..216983.39 rows=6 width=1) (actual time=988.738..1018.964 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: seniority
  Buffers: shared hit=199527 dirtied=5
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=216982.74..216983.39 rows=6 width=1) (actual time=980.932..1011.157 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: seniority
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=199527 dirtied=5
        ->  Sort  (cost=215982.74..215982.74 rows=3 width=1) (actual time=959.233..959.234 rows=0 loops=3)
              Output: seniority
              Sort Key: companies_employee.seniority
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              Buffers: shared hit=199527 dirtied=5
              Worker 0:  actual time=957.414..957.414 rows=0 loops=1
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                JIT:
                  Functions: 4
                  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
                  Timing: Generation 1.179 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.879 ms, Emission 9.714 ms, Total 11.771 ms
                Buffers: shared hit=54855 dirtied=2
              Worker 1:  actual time=939.591..939.592 rows=0 loops=1
                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                JIT:
                  Functions: 4
                  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
                  Timing: Generation 0.741 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.654 ms, Emission 6.531 ms, Total 7.926 ms
                Buffers: shared hit=87867 dirtied=1
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.companies_employee  (cost=0.00..215982.73 rows=3 width=1) (actual time=705.244..959.146 rows=0 loops=3)
                    Output: seniority
                    Filter: (((companies_employee.seniority)::text <> ''::text) AND (upper(companies_employee.title) ~~ '%INFORMATION SPECIALIST%'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2939330
                    Buffers: shared hit=199449 dirtied=5
                    Worker 0:  actual time=957.262..957.262 rows=0 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=54816 dirtied=2
                    Worker 1:  actual time=939.491..939.491 rows=0 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=87828 dirtied=1
Query Identifier: 2827140323627869732
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=293 read=1 dirtied=1
  I/O Timings: read=0.021
Planning Time: 1.078 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 13
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 2.746 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.224 ms, Emission 23.189 ms, Total 28.160 ms
Execution Time: 1050.493 ms
```

I confirmed the model indexes are identical for my local database and on Heroku, this is what they are:

```
  indexname                   |                                                             indexdef                                                              
----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 companies_employee_pkey                      | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX companies_employee_pkey ON public.companies_employee USING btree (id)
 companies_employee_company_id_c24081a8       | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_company_id_c24081a8 ON public.companies_employee USING btree (company_id)
 companies_employee_person_id_936e5c6a        | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_person_id_936e5c6a ON public.companies_employee USING btree (person_id)
 companies_employee_role_8772f722             | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_role_8772f722 ON public.companies_employee USING btree (role)
 companies_employee_role_8772f722_like        | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_role_8772f722_like ON public.companies_employee USING btree (role text_pattern_ops)
 companies_employee_seniority_b10393ff        | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_seniority_b10393ff ON public.companies_employee USING btree (seniority)
 companies_employee_seniority_b10393ff_like   | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_seniority_b10393ff_like ON public.companies_employee USING btree (seniority varchar_pattern_ops)
 companies_employee_title_78009330            | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_title_78009330 ON public.companies_employee USING btree (title)
 companies_employee_title_78009330_like       | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_title_78009330_like ON public.companies_employee USING btree (title text_pattern_ops)
 companies_employee_institution_75d6c7e9      | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_institution_75d6c7e9 ON public.companies_employee USING btree (institution)
 companies_employee_institution_75d6c7e9_like | CREATE INDEX companies_employee_institution_75d6c7e9_like ON public.companies_employee USING btree (institution text_pattern_ops)
 companies_e_seniori_12ac68_idx               | CREATE INDEX companies_e_seniori_12ac68_idx ON public.companies_employee USING btree (seniority, title)
 title_seniority                              | CREATE INDEX title_seniority ON public.companies_employee USING btree (upper(title), seniority)
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? (In some readable plain text format)

Comment: @FrankHeikens updated explains above to include analyze, verbose, buffers

Comment: Those two plans look very similar, certainly one is not 1000x slower than the other.

Comment: @jjanes in actual timed execution time the local one runs in ~0.3 seconds and the Heroku one runs in ~3, so about a 10x difference.